# Mean over one column based on time period + conditional of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, I could not sort it out by my own.

I made up this dataframe as a simpler example of the problem that I am facing. What I need, is for every 10 minutes, calculate the mean speed of the considered points, which are denoted by the column 'Status', 1 is considered and 0 is not. Hence, I expect to create a dataframe which contains 6 means values for each 10-min, however, the mean is relative to just the considered points.

```
            Timestamp      Category  ...      Status           Quantity
0     2013-08-14 22:00:00         1  ...          1               1
1     2013-08-14 22:00:01         1  ...          1               1
2     2013-08-14 22:00:02         1  ...          0               1.1
3     2013-08-14 22:00:03         1  ...          1               1.2
4     2013-08-14 22:00:04         1  ...          1               1.2
5     2013-08-14 22:00:05         1  ...          0               1.2
6     2013-08-14 22:00:06         1  ...          1               1.2
7     2013-08-14 22:00:07         1  ...          0               1.2
8     2013-08-14 22:00:08         1  ...          1               1.2

35999 2013-08-23 22:59:59         0  ...          1               2.3
```

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need first filter by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then resampling by [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `mean`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

df1=df.query("Status==1").resample('10Min',on='Timestamp')['Quantity'].mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
               Timestamp  Quantity
0    2013-08-14 22:00:00  1.133333
1    2013-08-14 22:10:00       NaN
2    2013-08-14 22:20:00       NaN
3    2013-08-14 22:30:00       NaN
4    2013-08-14 22:40:00       NaN
                 ...       ...
1297 2013-08-23 22:10:00       NaN
1298 2013-08-23 22:20:00       NaN
1299 2013-08-23 22:30:00       NaN
1300 2013-08-23 22:40:00       NaN
1301 2013-08-23 22:50:00  2.300000

[1302 rows x 2 columns]
```

Similar:

```
df1 = df[df["Status"] == 1].resample('10Min', on='Timestamp')['Quantity'].mean()
```

Comment: But on my case, what I am looking for is to calculate the mean of the column "Quantity"